# Disable Black formatting of dict expression within mapping comprehensions

Tags: python, formatting, python-black

I'm currently researching [Black](https://github.com/psf/black/) as our default formatter, but, I'm having some edge cases that don't format well and I want to know if there's a way to get the result I want.

[Black](https://github.com/psf/black/)'s documentation [partially explores my problem](https://github.com/psf/black/#the-magic-trailing-comma), I have a dictionary expression spread horizontally, and I want to keep it that way since I'm expecting lines to be added, e.g.:

```py
# Black would keep this as-is because of the trailing comma
TRANSLATIONS = {
    "en_us": "English (US)",
    "pl_pl": "polski",
}
```

But in my case the dictionary is inside a list comprehension:

```py
res = [
    {
        'id': item.id,
        'name': item.name,
    }
    for item in items.select()
]
```

Which Black collapses, regardless of the trailing comma, like so:

```py
res = [
    {"id": item.id, "name": item.name,}
    for item in items.select()
]
```

Is there a way of telling Black to retain the horizontal structure in these cases?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that **black** addressed this issue.

At the time of writing this answer, using **black** version `20.8b1`, the formatting is done as I was hoping for.

As long as there is a [magic trailing comma](https://github.com/psf/black/blob/main/docs/the_black_code_style/current_style.md#the-magic-trailing-comma) on the last item in the dictionary expression, black will format the code within the list comprehension.

```py
res = [
    {
        "id": item.id, "name": item.name,
    }
    for item in items.select()
]
```

Will format to:

```py
res = [
    {
        "id": item.id,
        "name": item.name,
    }
    for item in items.select()
]
```

Comment: Neat! This works with regular dictionaries too, not only ones part of a comprehension.

Answer (score 13):

You can use the `# fmt: off` / `# fmt: on` feature.

As you can see below:

- The list comprehension before the `# fmt: off` has been formatted by Black
- Between the `# fmt: off` / `# fmt: on` the list comprehension hasn't been formatted by Black
- The list comprehension after `# fmt: on` has been formatted by Black

**Code (after formatting by Black):**

```
res1 = [{"id": item[0], "name": item[1],} for item in [[5, "foo"], [6, "bar"]]]

# fmt: off
res2 = [
    {
        'id': item[0],
        'name': item[1],
    }
    for item in [[7, "fooo"], [8, "barr"]]
]
# fmt: on

res3 = [{"id": item[0], "name": item[1],} for item in [[9, "fooo0"], [10, "barrr"]]]

print(res1)
print(res2)
print(res3)
```

**Output of Python balck:**

```
/home/milanbalazs/.local/bin/black --fast -l 100 -v /home/milanbalazs/test.py
reformatted /home/milanbalazs/test.py
All done! ✨  ✨
1 file reformatted.
```

**Output of code:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
[{'id': 5, 'name': 'foo'}, {'id': 6, 'name': 'bar'}]
[{'id': 7, 'name': 'fooo'}, {'id': 8, 'name': 'barr'}]
[{'id': 9, 'name': 'fooo0'}, {'id': 10, 'name': 'barrr'}]
```

Related part of Black documentation: https://github.com/psf/black#the-black-code-style

Comment: I'm aware it's possible to disable formatting for segments of code this way but I am more interested in whether I can make Black play nice without disabling formatting of these sections.

Comment: I was wondering if there is some way without actually commenting the dict, maybe in the argument's list of black.